# How does orientation change vary from just a normal activity start?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I've noticed a few situations where consecutive orientation changes will crash my app, due to the use of fragments and views that I'm trying to access not having fully loaded yet.

The strange part of this is that they normally load just fine. Even a single orientation change loads fine. But going back to the original orientation crashes the app, with no other changes. I've seen this several times.

I don't have a specific example, more curious why it would make any difference at all. Does an orientation change load things differently than just normally launching the activity in question?

Comment: Have you handled screen orientation in android xml file?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)?

Comment: Yep, it has its own layout, and all the buttons match

Comment: @lsa thanks for that! That might well answer my question